# Compile to 64-bit target in Netbeans

Tags: java, opencv, dll, loadlibrary

I've made a 64-bit application (meaning it uses 64-bit DLLs (OpenCV for Java to be exact)) in Netbeans and using the inherit Run function works fine but if I try to build it and run the jar, it gives me this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java246 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.chimeras1684.ui.operation.NewDriverUI.main(NewDriverUI.java:43)
```

I've looked around a bit and it seems that the problem is that Netbeans run function builds in 64-bit but the build function builds for 32-bit. Is there a way to force the build to build for 64-bit? Or is the problem something else that I don't see?

Comment: How are you running the jar file? Double-click? Have you considered that the system installed jvm could be 32-bit? Java bytecode has no 'bit-size', it is entirely dependent on the running jvm.

Comment: Java has no concept of a built for 64-bit or 32-bit.  It is the JVM you choose to run it in which determines the bitness.

Comment: Is there a way to make the jar auto-run in 64-bit? (yes im double clicking)

Comment: Once the java program starts you cannot 'change' the bit-depth (since the jvm already started)... There isn't really a programmatic way in java to do this. You can however detect if its 64-bit or not and proceed/terminate accordingly. 32-bit/64-bit java doesn't have much difference apart from the fact that 64-bit java can allocate more memory, unless your external library benefits greatly from 64-bit execution I suggest compiling a 32-bit version as well (of the library).